# Why is Karl Tagon allowed to be an officer of Tagon's Toughs?

Tags: comics, webcomics, schlock-mercenary

Why did the U.N.S. military allow Karl Tagon to serve as an officer in Tagon's Toughs after the company's first stint working for the Oafans? It's well-established that the U.N.S. gets displeased with its generals becoming prominent in other organizations. Karl [said as much himself](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2005-02-19) the first time he joined up with the Toughs, in what became the alternate timeline:

> I told you, I can't take a job with any military outfit. Celeschul law: ex-generals have quiet retirements, or treason trials.

Under somewhat different circumstances, this was [pointed out to Xinchub](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2007-06-03) as well:

> The U.N.S. has very strict laws regarding officers deserting their posts and becoming kings.

In that first case, Tagon's presence was explained away as role-playing, and the U.N.S. had bigger problems on its plate (i.e. the Paan'uri war) right up until the point when those bigger problems destroyed the galaxy. However, he's now [employed as a commodore](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2014-03-20) in less frantic circumstances, which I doubt can be hand-waved away as a fantasy camp experience. So why didn't anyone go after him, even though he entered U.N.S. territory? Did the U.N.S. not know about his new job? Could the reward of capturing and trying him not have been worth the risk? Was the company's diplomatic immunity shielding him? Or was something else going on?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but wasn't Xinchub in active service (as opposed to Karl Tagon who was retired)?

Comment: You're not wrong, he was active. (Well, as active as you can be when you're captured.) I'm not sure how that's relevant here, though. The spirit of the law seems to be "if you're talented, don't use those talents anywhere but here."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is discussed in Big, Dumb Objects](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2015-07-08). It pretty much comes down to if the U.N.S make an issue of it the [details of Karl's kidnapping](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2015-07-10) and the [U.N.S's lack of response](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2015-07-11) would come public.  Also, Karl has enough [political connections](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2015-07-09) and "knowledge of where the bodies are buried" that he could induce the Legislature to change Celechul's "Special Assets" law (that he originally wrote).  As much power Xinchub had, he didn't have access to it while cut off and trapped on Yoming.